# Can't install any search provider in IE11

Tags: internet-explorer-11

Windows 8.1 Enterprise with all latest updates installed, IE11 ver.11.0.18

When I try to install any search provider from IE gallery, e.g. Google search  http://www.iegallery.com/en-us/Addons/Details/813 then click to button "Add to IE" does nothing. Fiddler shows that button click fails with:

```
   HTTP/1.1 302 Found
   Cache-Control: private
   Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
   Location: /Account/TimeOut?ReturnUrl=%2fAccount%2fTrackResourceInstall%3fresourceId%3d813%26userId%3d00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000&resourceId=813&userId=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
   Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
   X-AspNetMvc-Version: 3.0
   X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
   X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
   Date: Fri, 08 May 2015 15:03:12 GMT
   Content-Length: 311

   <html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
   <h2>Object moved to <a href="/Account/TimeOut?ReturnUrl=%2fAccount%2fTrackResourceInstall%3fresourceId%3d813%26userId%3d00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000&amp;resourceId=813&amp;userId=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000">here</a>.</h2>
   </body></html>
```

Any ideas what's wrong and how to fix?

Comment: There's a report that the April 15 security update broke this API: https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/Feedback/Details/1255678.  To date, the only public response I've seen is "We'll look into it."

Comment: It was fixed after installing MS Windows Updates in May 2015.